# Multiple Entries post under One ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I'm currently stuck with how to implement something into a database. I need multiple values to be carried over to a general page. To explain more in depth, let me tell you what I have done, and where I'm stuck.

I'm creating a New General Page form. I have a special offer form box generator, which upon pressing a button creates a new form consisting of six fields. For each new page, you can generate an infinite amount of offers. The problem I'd face if I give each offer an ID which gets imported to the general page is that it might either take ID=1 for one page and ID=2 for another page, or ID=1 and ID=2 will both be one every new page generated. What I need to do is  get, for example, 4 offers for one page sent to the database, and when the New Page is generated it'll have the four offers called. How would I go about creating a database for them?
Momentarily my table for it looks as such:

```
||idOffer||price||idDays||idPersonQuant||offerInfo
```

where ID Days and ID Person Quantity is unique to the individual offer.

I know I have to get all of the offers under one ID which will be unique to every page, but how do I get various amounts of offers under one ID?

For those who want to get a look at the script, here it is: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwoz0h9q/)
It works, but not on JS Fiddle.

If there is any confusion, I will post a JSFiddle with my code for the entire form and how it's going to post stuff.

Thanks in advance! Been stuck on this for ages :/

Comment: your jsfiddle is empty :P

Comment: haha sorry now it's up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple "offers" under one ID, you can create a new table called offerGroup (or similar).  Entries in this table will correspond to one "page", so when a new page is created, there should also be an associated offerGroup.  The table wouldn't need to be complicated at all, just a primary key:

```
||idGroup
```

In the "offer" table, you can then reference the id of the group that the offer belongs to.

```
||idOffer||price||idDays||idPersonQuant||offerInfo||**idGroup**
```

This solves your problem where you might have anywhere from one to infinity offers on one page.  I hope I understood your question correctly.